# Laravel auth guard check fails with valid auth cookie

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-6

The background is I'm updating a Laravel project using Laravel Shift and currently doing the jump from 5.8 to 6. The authentication has broken and I've troubleshoot it to the point where I'm not sure how to narrow it down any more than I already have.

I've confirmed the following

- The login is successful. Auth::user() is set as expected in the login request.
- The sessions table creates the session record (I've also tried file session driver but get the same issue)
- Auth Cookies are passed to client through Set-Cookie, stored, and passed to server in future requests.
- In future requests, the auth middleware runs, receives the auth cookies with correct keys and matching values in the session table, and uses the expected guard
- The guard check fails

Specifically I've did dumps inside `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Auth/Middleware/Authenticate.php`, where `$this->auth->guard($guard)` does show to be using the expected guard and has the auth cookie in the request. However the `->check()` returns false, resulting in 302 to login form and `Auth::user()` to be null.

The auth middleware gives the same behavior when used in router as `auth:api` or in controller as `$this->middleware('auth:api');`

Here is my `config/auth.php`

```
'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],
    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'passport',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],
],
'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\User::class,
    ],
],
```

Here is my LoginController method

```
private function loginUser($input, $request)
{
    $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');
    if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
        $request->session()->regenerate();
        // dd(Auth::user()); // This gets run and is set
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

I'm seeking advice on further troubleshooting this auth issue. Everything before `$this->auth->guard($guard)->check()` seems as I would expect, and I'm unsure what to check for at this point. Any and all help appreciated.

Comment: Are you using Laravel Passport ?

Comment: Why are you replacing the `Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers::login()` method? Step one would be getting rid of that custom function and using `$this->login()`; you don't appear to be doing anything that would require an override.